# Creating a thread taking way too long

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm experimenting with threads. My program is supposed to take a vector and sum it by breaking it down into different sections and creating a thread to sum each section. Currently, my vector has `5 * 10^8` elements, which should be easily handled by my pc. However, the creation of each thread (4 threads in my case) takes an insanely long time. I'm wondering why...?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <ctime>

std::mutex m;
int ans = 0;

void sumPart(const std::vector<int>& v, int a, int b){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
    ans += std::accumulate(v.begin()+a, v.begin()+b, 0); 
}

void sum(const std::vector<int>& v){
    //threadCount is 4 on my pc
    int threadCount = std::max(2, (int)std::thread::hardware_concurrency()/2);
    int sz = v.size()/threadCount;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++){
        clock_t start = clock();
        threads.push_back(std::thread(sumPart, v, sz*i, sz*(i+1)));
        std::cout << "thread " << i+1 << " took "  << (clock()-start)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000) << " ms to create" << std::endl;
    }
    
    for(std::thread& t : threads){
        t.join();
    }
    //the leftovers
    ans += std::accumulate(v.begin()+(threadCount)*sz, v.end(), 0);
}

int main(){
    const int N = 5e8;
    std::vector<int> v(N);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        v[i] = i;
    }

    sum(v);
    std::cout << ans << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
thread 1 took 681 ms to create
thread 2 took 824 ms to create
thread 3 took 818 ms to create
thread 4 took 814 ms to create
1711656320
```

Also, if I decrease the number of elements in vector, the time it takes to create each thread decreases as well, which is weird...
(Also I know I'm getting int overflow but that's besides the point)

Comment: The lock guard is effectively making the threads happen in serial.

Comment: You're passing a copy of that vector for each thread, the copying of which ain't cheap. Change the second argument on the thread create to `std::ref(v)` and rerun.

Comment: When you create a `std::thread` that thread will start immediately. There's no guarantee that the creator thread will keep running while this happens (it might, however). Also all those threads will try to acquire the same mutex.

Comment: Hint: `runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147450880 + 65536 cannot be represented in type 'int'`

Comment: To follow up on the comment by @Eljay -- that lock guard effectively makes all the threads run serially. Calculate the sum outside of the lock, storing the result in a local variable. Then lock the lock and add the result to `ans`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
   std::thread(sumPart, v, sz*i, sz*(i+1))
```

Arguments to thread functions are copied, as part of creating the execution thread.

Even though `sumPart` takes it parameter by value `v` gets internally copied. copying a vector with 500000000 values will take a little bit of time.

You can use [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to effectively pass `v` by reference to your thread function. Note, as it has been mentioned, your lock will single-thread all of your execution threads. However they'll be started very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Code calculating sum of all elements of a vector using multiple threads can be improved.

It doesn't require mutex at all,
It doesn't require `void sumPart(const std::vector<int>& v, int a, int b)` wrapper function over `std::accumulate`,
It doesn't require to pass `std::vector`, passing iterators are enough.
See following code,

```
#include <iostream>

#include <atomic>
#include <future>

#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

long long int sum(std::vector<int>::const_iterator firstIt,
                  std::vector<int>::const_iterator lastIt){

    std::vector<std::future<long long int>> futureList;
    int elementCount = (lastIt - firstIt) / std::max<int>(
                2, std::thread::hardware_concurrency() / 2);

    std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = firstIt;
    auto accumulateFun = std::accumulate<std::vector<int>::const_iterator,
            long long int>;

    long long total = 0;

    while(lastIt - it > elementCount){

        futureList.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, accumulateFun, it,
                                           it + elementCount, total));
        it += elementCount;
    }

    total += std::accumulate(it, lastIt, total);

    for(std::future<long long int>& f : futureList){

        total += f.get();
    }

    return total;
}

int main(int , char *[]){

    const int N = 5e8;
    std::vector<int> numList(N);

    std::iota(numList.begin(), numList.end(), 0);

    std::cout<< sum(numList.cbegin(), numList.cend()) << '\n';
}
```